# suppose char *p = "hello world", so is there any '\0' exist right after the 'd'?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
     char *p = "hello world";
     int a = (int)(*(p+strlen(p)+1)); // equal to a=(int)(*p+12)
     printf("%d\n", a);
     return 0;
}
```

a is not '\0', why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
     char *p = "hello world";
     int a = (int)(*(p+strlen(p)+1)); // equal to a=(int)(*p+12)
     for(int i=0; p[i]!='\0'; i++)
         printf("%c",p[i]);
     return 0;
}
```

return: hello world
so, i wonder if '\0' do exist at the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question, yes, C always adds a terminating `\0` to a string literal.

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = (int)(*(p+strlen(p)+1));
```

You are exceeding one more ..

you need to define like this

```
int a = (int)(*(p+strlen(p)));  //now a consists 0 integer value of null
```

let see this

```
char *p ="abc";
p   ==>a 
p+1 ==>b
p+2 ==>c 
p+3 ==>null
```

**EDIT:**
`C- adds '\0' implicitly` when you initializes direct string.
but when ever if you initializes statically you would found some difference.

these both equal strings

```
 char *p = "helloworld";
 char q[]={'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
```

these are not

```
 char *p = "helloworld";
 char q[]={'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d'};
```

observe the result with this

```
if (!strcmp(p,q))
 printf("both are same\n ");
```

Comment: so what i mean is if there is an '\0' do exist at the end of the string. it is "hello world" or ''h''e''l''l''o' 'w''o''r''l''d''\0'?

Comment: @user2046815 Added some more info to the answer.would be helpful. Explains what you require.

Comment: In the examples, `p` is a valid C-string but `q` is not -- *precisely* because it does not end with a 0 byte. `strcmp` expects valid C-strings, and using it to compare `p` and `q` here results in [undefined behavior](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior). The byte 'after' `q` in memory can be zero, or any other random value, and the result of `strcmp` cannot be predicted.

Comment: @Jongware thank you very much for posting this helpful comment.Yes that would give undefined behavior. I was tested too.i was given that as an example to show some difference between defining with string and with single characters.

Answer (score 2):

You're out by 1, reading the value 1 byte beyond the nul terminator.  Try

```
int a = *(p+strlen(p));
```

instead

Comment: yes, i do it deliberately to know what's the character after 'd'. so what i mean is if there is an '\0' do exist at the end of the string.

Comment: There is a nul terminator at the end of your string. Your code reads 1 byte too far; my suggested change will read the terminator

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you take simple string. like char a[6]= {'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};
you need to write null pointer externally but in direct string or with pointer variable compiler do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, \0 is located 11 notches after *p and not 12.

Comment: thanks for all your help. totally make sense.actually, i am exceeding "two" more!